# Use Git with existing files and update branch after push

Tags: git, git-branch, git-push, git-pull

we are currently starting to work with Git and run into some trouble.

Baiscally what i want is to have a Git-Repository that users can push to and pull from.

Also this repository should work as Preview Version of the master branch, so we need to have the script files in the repository itself.

I initiated the repository with "git init test.git". So it's not a bare repo.

Question is how to setup git that it holds the current version of the master branch as real files and i can setup a url to reach the current master branch of the repository.

When i create a repository and try to push to it i get an error that the current master branch is checked out on the repository and i cant push to it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must not push to a non bare repository! You cannot push to a checked out branch!

Now given you situation my suggestion is:

Keep a blessed bare repository! Do all your development on the local, merge/rebase on master and then push to blessed bare.

You can write the post-receive hook of the blessed bare that it has a code/runs a script that has code to `cd` into your production repo, and pull from blessed bare.(it will be a fast-forward as you might have resolved conflicts before pushing to blessed bare)

This way, on every push to 'blessed bare', you pull into the production and update the checked out master!

Hope this solves the problem.

Happy gitting!

Comment: that seems like a good solution :)
Have you tried this?
I have a post-receive script now that goes to the correct directory via cd like this

cd /var/www/.../
git pull

but nothing happends
if i call the script by hand it gets executed correctly

Comment: @phil: Good to know you like the solution. No I haven't tried this, but i have done something similar and hence I knew it would work. Nothing happens when you execute the script by hand because whatever had to happen has already happened when you pushed to the `blessed_bare`.

Answer (score -1):

Based on what you have described, then I think implementing the branching strategy known as [GitFlow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) might work for you.

Comment: I don't think it addresses the issue at all. And it seems to be just a regular git workflow except that 'master' is renamed to 'develop'. Plus it seems to fail in a multi-version environment as hotfixes are done on master.

Comment: Did you even read the blog post?!?  There are two branches.  One master, and one develop.  With regard to this question, all work is done on the develop branch, with feature and releases created and instantiated from the develop branch.  Then, as work is completed, and tested, they are pushed to the protected master branch.  Yes, hotfixes are done in master branch, specifically for the reason that you point out, i.e. to allow for multi-version support.

Comment: Yes, I did read the blog post, that's why I was talking about its contents.

Comment: But master isn't just "renamed" to develop.  There are two active branches.