# How to set the root application directory?

Tags: git, digital-ocean, dokku

I have created my first droplet, but I don't know how to set the root application directory?
I tried to create a folder for my app name in `/home/dokku/app_name`
Then, I did `cd app_name` and then `git init`
Then I added a remote repo:

```
git remote add dokku root@do.mydomain.com:app_name
```

But, when try to push I get error:

```
fatal: 'app_name' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

How to configure this? How to set the root application directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the following steps if you haven't:

(on server)

1. Login to server as root. cd ~ (Go to home dir of root)
2. `cd app_name`
3. `git init --bare` (It should give you message that it initialized a git repo)

(Local System)

1. `cd app_name`
2. `git init` (It should give you message that it initialized a git repo)
3. `git add .` (to stage all files in current dir to commit)
4. `git commit`
5. `git remote add dokku root@do.mydomain.com:app_name`
6. `git push dokku master` (first time you need to9 give the name of branch to push as remote repo does not have any branch of itself yet.

Hope this solves your prob!

Comment: Thank you! now git push is in progress, but how would I let www.do.mydomain.com points to rails server when I run it?

Comment: @Simo: Good to know it works! See if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25969974/use-git-with-existing-files-and-update-branch-after-push) help to let rails server know when to run.