# Cannot push git repo to Dokku remote on Digital Ocean droplet?

Tags: git, ssh, openssh, digital-ocean, dokku

Edit/update: instead of creating my git repo in the root, I created it in the dokku folder. Now when I push, I get this:

```
bash-3.1$ ssh-add id_rsa; git push dokku master
Identity added: id_rsa (id_rsa)
Counting objects: 16, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (14/14), done.
Writing objects: 100% (16/16), 3.83 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 16 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
To dokku@jlchang.me:LeagueSides
 * [new branch]      master -> master
```

Which indicates my git bash has access to the dokku folder and is able to push there, but Dokku doesn't seem to recognize the repo and is not building/deploying the app. I've read elsewhere that you are not supposed to create the repo yourself on the server, that git remote add takes care of that, but that did not work for me. Is there something I'm missing in the app?

Original post:

I am using Windows 7 with OpenSSH. I recently set up a ubuntu-dokku droplet on Digital Ocean and configured my SSH key. I can currently log in to either the dokku or root username on my droplet without a password using Putty, WinSCP, and ssh at the command line (OpenSSH).

However, I am having issues trying to push my repo onto dokku. I have my repo set up on my local machine (and it is sync'd up with my Github remote), and then ran the following:

```
git remote add host dokku@<mydomain>:LeagueSides.<mydomain>
git push host master
```

When I did that, I got the following error:

```
c:\Code\Projects\LeagueSides> git push host master 
fatal: 'LeagueSides.<mydomain>' does not appear to be a git repository 
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Please make sure you have the correct access rights 
and the repository exists.

I get the same error if I call:

```
ssh-agent bash -c 'ssh-add c:\users/<myuser>/.ssh/id_rsa; git push host master
```

I also tried the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25971857/4131871) but still got the same error.

Is there a step I'm missing? Did I do something wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is your remote repository name?

Comment: @MudassirRazvi LeagueSides

So I logged in as dokku via Putty, and created a directory called LeagueSides within the dokku folder and called "git init --bare" like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25971857/4131871) and I got it to push, but dokku did not actually deploy the app. Does my app need to meet certain requirements for dokku to deploy it?

Comment: Your repo on dokku is a bare repo. It does not have any "files" checked out to deploy. See if this[1] helps.

[1] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25969974/use-git-with-existing-files-and-update-branch-after-push

Comment: @MudassirRazvi I meant that after creating a bare repo, I was able to push my local repo to it so the files are there, but dokku doesnt seem to notice it. I put the log at the top of my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I destroyed my droplet and re-created it. FWIW, this [guide](https://gist.github.com/ngoldman/7287753) says to name your droplet after your hostname (if you plan to use the domain example.com, name your droplet "example.com") and it worked.